# coloring a part of the Histogram using dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, colors, histogram

```
dic={-0.018273:"cluster0",0.473295:"cluster2",30.07545:"cluster1",0.05741:"cluster0"}
```

If my dictionary is as above but with many elements and I use the following python code to plot it

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(data.keys(),bins=20)
plt.show()
```

I get a histogram with a single color.
But I want a histogram that looks like the one below
[image]

The colors corresponds to the values of the dictionary

for eg:
Red color stands for cluster0 and 
blue stands for cluster1

What changes should I make to my code?

Comment: What is `cluster0`?  Is it a string? Integer? Array?  And by "many elements" do you mean that you have multiple floating point numbers as *keys* that all have an identical value?  If so, consider restructuring that dictionary so that a single "cluster0" key has all its values.

Comment: yes multiple floating point numbers as keys that all have an identical value. What do I do after that reconstructing the dictionary as you suggest?

Comment: Then my suggestion is to flip that around - make an array from those floating points and store it in a *single* key for each cluster. Then you can histogram them separately to your heart's content. Just call `hist` multiple times.

Comment: Yeah it worked thanks for the suggestion.